# MySQL query to get only one record: either when end_date is null or max(end_date)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, relational-database

I have the following table (`employee_organization`):

| ID | employee_id | organization_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 77 | 16 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-30 |
| 2 | 11 | 23 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-05-27 |
| 3 | 77 | 16 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-31 |
| 4 | 77 | 16 | 2021-09-01 | NULL |

I need a query to filter out records where `employee_id = 77`, `organization_id = 16` and `end_date is null`. If no matching row has been found, than return a row with `max(end_date)`. So, in the above sample table only row with `id=4` should be returned.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If none of those case matches `max` can be fore any of those values as well?

Comment: I have updated the sample table ... If row ID=4 wasn't there, I would expect result row with ID=3. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE {needed conditions}
ORDER BY end_date IS NULL DESC, end_date DESC LIMIT 1
```